# How to generate the bytecode of a loop instruction

Tags: antlr, grammar, bytecode

I have a grammar that contains a rule like this:

```
stmt -> ID := expr
      | print( expr )
      | if( expr ) then ( stmt ) [ else stmt ]?
      | while( expr ) do stmt
      | begin stmt [ ; stmt ]* end
```

I don't know how to translate the rule WHILE to bytecode. For now, I wrote this:

```
stmt 
    : ID ':''=' expr 
        { 
            if(st.lookupType($ID.text) != $expr.type) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type error on variable: " + $ID.text + ".");    
            }
            int var = st.lookupAddress($ID.text);
            code.emit(Opcode.ISTORE, var);
        }
    | 'print' '(' expr ')' 
        {
            if($expr.type == Type.INTEGER) {
                code.emit(Opcode.PRINT);
            }
            if($expr.type == Type.BOOLEAN) {
                code.emit(Opcode.BPRINT);           
            }
        }
    | 'if' expr 
        {
            if($expr.type != Type.BOOLEAN)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type error in '( expr )': expr is not a boolean."); 
            int ltrue = code.newLabel();    
        }
        'then'  
        {
            code.emit(Opcode.LABEL, ltrue);
        }
        s1 = stmt ( 'else' s2 = stmt )?
    | 'while' expr 
        { 
            if($expr.type != Type.BOOLEAN)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type error in '( expr )': expr is not a boolean."); 
            //Bytecode generator
            // CODE...
        }   
        'do' 
        ( 
            s1 = stmt 
            {
                int ltrue = code.newLabel();    
            }
        )*      
    | 'begin' s1 = stmt ( ';' s2 = stmt )* 'end'    
    ;
```

`st` is a symbol table, that is, a table that contains the type of a certain variable.

In my grammar can be only two types: INTEGER or BOOLEAN.

The method `newLabel()` does nothing more than create a new label that is a string such as L1, L2, L3, etc., simply incrementing a counter.

`code` is an instance of CodeGenerator that is a data structure (`Vector <Instruction>`)  that stores the bytecode instructions generated during the parsing of a program.

The `Instruction` class is composed of two fields (`opcode` and `operand`) and represents a single byte code instruction.

How do I generate the bytecode of a loop such as WHILE? 
Thanks

---

Modified code:

```
'while' 
    {
        int lloop = code.newLabel(); //label for loop
        int ldone = code.newLabel(); //laber for done
        code.emit(Opcode.LABEL, lloop);
    }
    expr 
    { 
        if($expr.type != Type.BOOLEAN)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type error in '( expr )': expr is not a boolean."); 
        code.emit(Opcode.GOTO, ldone);
    }   
    'do' ( stmt )*
        code.emit(Opcode.GOTO, lloop);
        code.emit(Opcode.LABEL, ldone);
    }
```

Comment: This is a very vague question I'm afraid. We don't even know what your instruction set looks like so how can we tell you how to generate code from a while loop?

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy Thanks for the answer, what isn't clear? I can detail the question..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest expression of a while loop is:

```
LOOP:
      <condition>
      jmp_if_false DONE;
      <body>
      jmp LOOP
DONE:
```

which might translate in pseudocode into:

```
'while' {
               Create loop_label
               Create done_label
               Emit Label loop_label
        }
 expr   {
               Emit Jump_If_False to done_label
        }
 'do' stmt* {
               Emit Jump to loop_label
               Emit Label done_label
        }
```

There are a variety of possible optimizations, but that's a start at least.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, I modified the code according to your schema, but still doesn't work. Would you help me please? The modified code is in the next answer.. Thanks

Comment: @user3602008: I really can't help you much more because I have no idea what your intermediate language looks like. But the important part is that you need to *conditionally* jump to done_label. An unconditional jump will (obviously) skip the while body.